# Get blocks from Autocad /Maps into excel

Tags: excel, autocad

I would like to get some objects on a Autocad map layer and extract their name, color and position and place them into an excel sheet in the following manner:

Object Name |  Color | Coordinates

Is there any way to do that programatically? Is there any tool/plugin that already does that?

Comment: Does Autocad have an export feature? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

AutoCAD has a fairly complete data extraction utility known as the [data extraction wizard](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff1c7e22710db287822c-7fb7.htm,topicNumber=d0e217705) that will likely satisfy your needs with no programming required.

If your needs are more complex than what the data extraction wizard can do AutoCAD offers a complete [.NET API](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/index.html?url=WS73099cc142f48755-35a0330e12075abe904-7442.htm,topicNumber=d0e118)